# BItwise operator usage for multiple checkboxes to save and retrive in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

As i want to know about the storing of multiple checkbox values in `tinyint` (bitwise) in mysql table . for example if we have

```
`2=>car, 4=>bike, 8=>truck`
```

and if we select  car and bike check boxes in UI how the value will get stored in table . and how it can be viewed back to screen and gets edited.

Comment: You know MySQL has the ENUM and SET data types …?

Comment: That would be a poor design.

Comment: i am new to it .. i have used enum once and i thought to use bitwise operators to do it ..

Answer (score 0):

To combine checkboxes you can use bitwise OR `|`:

```
$value = 0;
$value |= 2;
$value |= 8;
// $value is 0b1010
```

To retrieve you can use bitwise AND `&`:

```
if($value & 8) {
  // '8' checkbox is set
}
```